# New FireMessagin version

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have updated my flutter project to the new firebase versions.

And I have encountered the following problem.

```
The method 'configure' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.
```

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        ...
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        ...
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        ...
      },
    );
```

How would you do with the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its old now : you can use this as per your requirement.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
});
```

check this link : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

Comment: Yes, for onMessage it works for me, but for onResume and onLaunch it doesn't. What should I do?

Comment: What exactrly you want on resume and  launch method ?

Comment: onResume -> print('on resume $message');
        LaunchReview.launch(androidAppId: "com.example.app",
            iOSAppId: "0000000000");

Comment: onLaunch -> print('on launch $message'); LaunchReview.launch(androidAppId: "com.example.app", iOSAppId: "0000000000");

Comment: onMessage -> print('on message $message'); LaunchReview.launch(androidAppId: "com.example.app", iOSAppId: "0000000000");

Comment: onLaunch is your method or fcm one ? and What is launch review ?

Comment: You want to launch something from onMessage right ?

Comment: A Flutter plugin to assist in leaving user reviews/ratings in Google Play Store and Apple App Store

Comment: To open the App Store page for any other applications, you can pass the app Id https://pub.dev/packages/launch_review

Comment: is there any error logs ?

Comment: I have no ideaa